# Selenium ChromeDriver not working in python3.5 ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting following error. Can someone assist me

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "index.py", line 38, in 
>      browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"./chromedriver") #replace with >.Firefox(), or with the browser of your choice
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist->packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in **init**
>       desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64)

Comment: do you also have the latest chromedriver? it matters sometimes. should be 2.4 right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chromdriver` is failing to launch your Chrome browser.  This is most likely due to using incompatible versions of Chrome browser and Chromedriver.

You didn't mention the version of Selenium bindings or Chrome browser you are using, but your stacktrace shows:

> chromedriver=2.35.528139

Chromedriver 2.35 only supports Chrome versions 62-64. The latest version (currently 2.40), supports Chrome versions 66-68.  If you upgrade to that, this should be solved.

In general, every time Chrome upgrades itself, you will need to replace Chromedriver with a newer version... or at least check compatibility.

You can see which versions a Chromedriver supports by checking the release notes on the Downloads page: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Thanks Corey. I used windows server instead of Ubuntu server. It works now.